# How can I communicate with component from Visualforce page which has embedded in iframe

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, javascript, slds, iframe

I have created one Lightning Component, and loading that from one Visualforce page. When I click on a button in Lightning Component, I am showing another Visualforce page as a Modal (popup) by using an Iframe. We can close that Modal by using an 'X' icon, which is calling the "CloseModal" method. That is fine.

Now, I aim to close the popup by using the Esc keyword. So, when I press Esc on the Visualforce page, it should call the "CloseModal" method.

I can communicate to the Lightning component from the VF page (from where I am loading the component) through "aura: method". But, I am unable to call the "CloseMethod" from VF Page, which has embedded in an iframe (Modal).

How can I achieve this?

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Thanks
Sannith

Comment: Have you looked at [Lightning Messages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service) as a solution to this situation? This new framework is designed to allow VF->LC communication, even across frames or windows, and may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with parent.postmessage in VF page and event listener in Component, this has resolved my issue.

For more details: [Visualfore page to Lightning Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html)

Thank you